# More powerful ESP9266 based microcontroller than nodemcu

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino, microcontroller

I am currently working with Nodemcu. I am running a very long code with many HTTP requests. After 3 http requests, the nodemcu gets crashed. It is unable to handle. I am looking for a WiFi microcontroller which runs on Arduino IDE and can support arduino libraries (because I am using many libraries). Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Why do you think you need a more powerful hardware? I mean, you are aware why your firmware "crashes"?

Comment: I figured it out. It happened due to heap overflow. I bought an esp32, and it is working well.